# Django - error 500 occurs when checking if value is None

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using Django to develop my server and came across a problem which I'm not sure why is happening.

I have the following model:

```
class Group(models.Model):

    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True)
    attached_rule = models.CharField(max_length=45, null=True)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, group_name, attached_rule=None):
        group = cls(group_name=group_name, attached_rule=attached_rule)
        return group

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name
```

I also have the following function in my views.py:

```
def get_rule_by_group(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        group_name = request.GET.get("groupName")
        print(group_name)
        group = Group.objects.filter(group_name=group_name)

        if group.attached_rule is None: #<== Fails here
            print("attached rule is null")

        return HttpResponse("Successful")
```

Now, when a group first created the value of **attached_rule** is null and will changed later on. The problem happens after I create the group, and then try to print the attached rule to console - I check if the rule is null. However, the server fails at this point and I get this error:

> "GET /policies/getRuleByGroup/?groupName=TestGroup HTTP/1.1" 500 58646

What can be causing this error?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
The problem was that I was using Group.objects.filter() instead of Group.objects.get()

Comment: If you run the server with `DEBUG=TRUE`, it will show a traceback. Can you post the traceback?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem
DEBUG is already set to True in my settings.py. Is there any other place I need to change it?

Comment: doesn't the webpage shows a traceback?

Comment: I was using postman to test the functionality, I was looking at the wrong tab, thanks for pointing out about the traceback.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `group` is a queryset, not a model instance. So it does not have the `attached_rule` attribute. Change:

```
group = Group.objects.filter(group_name=group_name)
```

to

```
group = Group.objects.get(group_name=group_name)
```

You might have to do some extra checking or exception handling if it is possible that there is no such group (or more than one).